# How my function know my object.value since I pass a void argument in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

Here a classic function to create components with Reactjs.

I call also a function to delete component by their "id". My component works with destructuring data. You will remark that I don't pass any real argument in my function call since it a classic argue "(id)" pass in instead of destructuring argument "({id})", how my function can knows the value of my object ? Because the delete effectively work ! Amazing.

here my function :

```
  return( 
            this.props.data.element.map(({id, title}) => { 
                return( 
                    <li key={id} className="collection-item">
                        {title}
                        <i
                         className="material-icons"
                         // the delete will work ! 
                         // despite I pass a classic argument in 
                         onClick={() => this.onSongDelete(id)}
                        >delete</i>
                    </li>
                )
            })
        )
```

Any hint would be great,
Thanks

Comment: please have a look to [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: I don't understand the question. The destructuring happens when mapping over the array of objects. This extracts `id` from the object, and passes that to `this.onSongDelete()` when you click on the element.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't pass any real argument"? Of course you're passing in an argument, `id`, it's right there, I can see it. Are you confused about closures?

Comment: thanks for your comments, effectively I was confused by curly braces but "id" value is effectively here and can be passed directly in the function braces without curly braces if I understand better